# Windows 10 audio sound recording dropouts - how to change buffer size?

Tags: windows-10, audio, audio-recording, windows-10-v1809

I have no playback problems, but I get crackles when recording. Example: https://instaud.io/3w6w

This came with the newest Windows update "[April 2, 2019—KB4490481 (OS Build 17763.404)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ph/help/4490481/windows-10-update-kb4490481)", which even does pertain to audio. Just installed it minutes ago (and rebooted).

Of course waiting for a fix of the fix might be the way - or just roll back (which I might). But independent of this, my extensive audio experience tells me an increase of buffer size will probably fix these quite cyclical crackles that keep happening.

(My Windows Sound settings are so that the "Stereo Mix" is recorded by Windows and outputted via the TV that is my screen. This recording - or any other - shows the problem. My main audio otherwise is the headphones plugged into the PC. Haven't had problems with any of this for months. I used audio recording software to verify that the recording itself is indeed the problem. Which software is not relevant - recording is affected in general.)

So - does anyone know how to adjust the buffer sizes? Weird enough, there are no Google hits for changing windows audio buffer size.

Comment: Edit your question to include what program you are using to record.

Comment: Made the wording a bit more clear. Windows itself is the recording software, via the Sound settings.

Comment: I assumed this (Screenshot https://i.imgur.com/9thkSLm.png) was common knowledge. Anyway, it does not matter which recording software I use. The problem is with recording, not with the software. I know this, because I experienced it as such.

Comment: Is there any chance the recording has crackles in it because it has crackles in it?  The Realtek / Nvidia High Definiton Audio software outputs the audio you hear.  On your "Stereo-mix Properties Page" check every tab for "Disable Hardware Acceleration". If that does not work roll back to the previous driver.  Read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic)  "Just installed it minutes ago".  Within "minutes" you've researched your problem, found no solutions, found / recorded an audio file example, and written this question?

Comment: ""Stereo Mix" is recorded by Windows." No it is not. "This recording - or any other - shows the problem." Yet "I have no playback problems". 
Aren't all of your "recordings" from before the update? You did it "minutes" ago.  "Haven't had problems with any of this for months." How did you solve the problem the last time it happened?
  "Weird enough, there are no Google hits for changing windows audio buffer size."  Windows is lucky if it can pat it's head and rub its stomach at the same time. 
 There are 22.6m google search results to "windows 10 audio buffer",

Comment: 1.16m results to "windows 10 audio buffer NVidia" and 684,000 results for "windows 10 audio buffer realtek".

Comment: Dude, are you TRYING to be obnoxious? You can't just count Google hits for a set of words, you also need to check if they pertain to the problem. Your hits are about extra software for musicians. And yes, I did all this within minutes, because I have been in IT for 3+ decades. ... "Yet I have no playback problems." Yes. Playback is fine. Recording is not. It's not complicated. Just take my word instead of trying to drag me into your nightmare. ... I never had this problem before, the "for months" statement is because I am speaking with maximum certainty, that's why the time frame is limited.

Comment: There's no hardware acceleration setting in any of the Stereo Mix tabs. And yes, Windows is recording the Stereo Mix. When you pipe it into a different output device by the "Listen" tab in the properties, you hear what your sound software would record. Which is why my above recording (which I added much later after creation of the question, Mister hobby-critic) shows exactly the crackles. I do not hear the crackles in my headphones, which don't have the recording-detour. I hear them through my TV which does have the recording-detour. Btw., currently problem is gone, may return later.